# cakephp customise password field

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am developing an application using cakephp 2.3.9 .It got a users table to save user credentials .How do i use a different `field` in `User` table other than `password` field to save password.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
           ......
        ),
        'authError' => '...',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => 
                    array(
                       'password' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD' // set custom field
                                                         // as password field
                    )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

in `AppController.php`.

And in your Form set `type="password"` to that field. e.g.

```
$this->Form->input('YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD', array('type' => 'password'));
```

---

Referencing [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722115/cakephp-customise-password-field/19722153?noredirect=1#comment29300153_19722153), to encrypt the password field you need to do manual approach in your controller or model. e.g. in controller you can do like:

```
$this->request->data['User']['YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD'] = AuthComponent::password( $this->request->data['User']['YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD']);
```

Also you can do model `beforeSave()` function also by proper checking in case of `add/edit` action.

---

Ref:

1. **[CakePHP Auth Password Hash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords)**
2. **[For detail about CakePHP Auth](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)**

Comment: Thank you so much for your immediate reply .I tried it and it is almost working, but one more problem that i am facing is i dont want to encrypt that custom password field . so how do i handle it .. do you have any idea?